# How do I make a simple dot "." in HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

In my Ruby on Rails Project I use HAML, I need to translate something like this

```
<div>foo <a>bar</a>.<div>
```

into HAML. It should look like:

```
.divclass
  foo
  %a bar
  .
```

The period at start is not working because its used by HAML. So how can I use a period as content?

Even with building a span around its not working, again the period is taken as something special.

I think there is an escape mechanism but I can't find it.

Comment: In HAML, as with most other languages, things are escaped with a backslash. It should be the first thing you try when moving to a new language.

Comment: HAML is also well documented: http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It is escaped with `\`

like this

```
\.
```

See [Escaping \](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#escaping_) in the HAML reference.

**Update:** Using HAML's `succeed` (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18346789/212245)) is a better solution if you need a dot in the end of the sentence (to prevent unnecessary white space).

Comment: The problem here is that in his case there will be a white space between the a tag and the dot. Prefer the `succeed` method from @Jay

Answer (score 20):

A better method:

```
%p
  This sentence ends with a link which is *just* before a period
  = succeed "." do
    %a{:href => "#"} link
  But the period wasn't included with the link and there was no space before the period.
```

Comment: An explanation of what makes this method better would be good.

Answer (score 2):

You also have access to the :plain filter, like this:

```
%p 
  :plain
    .
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to add another option using Rails' built-in `link_to` helper instead of manually creating the link. Then you can simply do

```
%p
  This sentence ends with a link which is *just* before a period
  #{ link_to "link", "#" }.
```

Different solutions will work in different places, but I find this to be quite clean, especially if already using `link_to` or `mail_to` etc.

Comment: This is definitely the way. Since we're clearly need interpolation here from the generic point of view.